# error "No rule to make target ..."when build opencv program ,and "undefined reference to" error

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros

I want to build my simple OpenCV program,but when I build the project,it failed and the error description is:

```
No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so,opencv_videostab', needed by `/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/multi_robot_slam/imageConverter'. Stop.
```

Here is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robot_slam)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    cmake_modules
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
    cv_bridge
    std_msgs
    image_transport
)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package()

add_executable(imageConverter src/imageConverter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(imageConverter ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

Does anybody know what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: That: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so,opencv_videostab` means that someone **incorrectly enumerate libraries via comma** instead of space. Have you modified `FindOpenCV.cmake`? Have you set some cache variables for find OpenCV?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your usefull answer.It seems like i incorrectly enumerate libraries via comma.But when i modified this.It come out new problems.'undefined reference to 'cv::namedWindow(...)' and all function i used which belong to namespace cv all undefined reference.I have add variables to /etc/profile like :
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH
OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/include
export OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opencv-3.2.0/build/bin

Comment: Undefined reference means that you didn't include the required header in your code. 'namedWindow()' is in  highgui.hpp

Comment: Nope,I have included corresponding header file already ,  like following                `#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <vector>`  And eclipse can give me code completion when i use the function of these files and have no error.However when i build the program it goes error:`**undefined reference to...**`

Comment: Describe your (new) problem **in the question post** by [edit] it. @QuangHoang: `Undefined reference` means **absence of the library**, not an absence of `#include` directive.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, what was I thinking. @Jack: is it `${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}` or `${OpenCV_LIBS}`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes,I agree.the `Undefined reference` problem all happened **after I download the opencv3.2.0 and build and install it**.I see there are some libopencv_*.so.2.4 and libopencv_*.so.2.4.8 in folder **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** and some libopencv_*.so.3.2 and libopencv_*.so.3.2.0 in folder **/usr/local/lib**. So does it possiblly  caused by version conflict **while the error info was not ....conflict**? How can i do or **how can i know which version does find_package used?**

Comment: @Quang Hoang Yes,it is .I think maybe the lib which is using is wrong,but it seems not.I don't understand as i am just a new cmake user.

Comment: The sample CMakeList.txt [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) says it's `${OpenCV_LIBS}`. Try print them out with `message ${OpenCV_LIBS}`

Comment: **Oh,I get it, the value of variable are** `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS:/usr/include/opencv/usr/include
OpenCV_LIBRARIES:opencv_videostabopencv_videoopencv_superresopencv_stitchingopencv_photoopencv_oclopencv_objdetectopencv_mlopencv_legacyopencv_imgprocopencv_highguiopencv_gpuopencv_flannopencv_features2dopencv_coreopencv_contribopencv_calib3d`   **and the output info is** `CMakeFiles/imageConverter.dir/src/imageConverter.cpp.o: In function cv::String::~String()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:664: undefined reference to cv::String::deallocate()'` **and other error info are like that**.

Comment: Oh,I solve it .That's amazing!Thanks very much @QuangHoang @Tsyvarev.The problem was really caused by the version.When i change `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` to `find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)` ,it works and build successfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by modified the comma to space.From it i learned that:

```
No rule to make target /usr/lib/x86_64linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so,opencv_videostab', needed by /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/multi_robot_slam/imageConverter'.Stop.
```

means that someone incorrectly enumerate libraries via comma instead of space.

And besides,I also solved the problem of

```
undefined reference to ***.
```

These problem usually means absence of the library, or there are more than one version lib on your computer.For me ,it is because the `#include<>` used the header files of opencv3.2 while the lib used of opencv2.4.So I modified `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` to `find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)` to make lib used is also opencv3.2.And then all problems disappeard and everything goes right!